# Calculating integral

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I need some help to solve this integral:

$$\int(x^2+y^2)^{-\frac32} \mathrm dx$$

Thank you.

Comment: Please ask 2 different questions.

Comment: An obvious substitution would be $x=y\sinh t$

Answer (score 1):

Put $x = y \tan t$ and $dx = y \sec^2 t\ dt$, then
$$
\begin{align}
\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{(x^2+y^2)^3}}&=\int\frac{y \sec^2 t\ dt}{\sqrt{(y^2\tan^2 t+y^2)^3}}\\
&=\int\frac{y \sec^2 t\ dt}{y^3\sec^3 t}\\
&=\frac{1}{y^2}\int\cos t\ dt\\
&=\frac{\sin t}{y^2}+C\\
&=\frac{x}{y^2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}+C.
\end{align}
$$

Comment: thanks, just one more little question: how did you return the sin(t)?

Comment: @GalDelariya Since $x=y\tan t$, then $\tan t=\dfrac xy$ and it is obvious $\sin t=\dfrac x{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: try the substitution $x=y\tan \theta$.